# Compiler Error Message: CS1583 while opening the asp.net mvc 2.0 website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, compiler-errors

Please help me .I have developed a site in asp.net mvc 2.0 and uploaded to the go daddy server.upto now it is working fine .Beu i have uploaded a simple view by downloading from FTP and edit some thing.after if i will open the website in the internet ,my site is not at all running.It shows the following error,

Server Error in '/dev' Application.

Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1583: 'c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\dev\5cedb4af\b58c4f58\CSC7383.tmp' is not a valid Win32 resource file

After this i have Undo those changes and again uploaded through FTP.But it shows the same error.Please Tell me my mistake and how to solve this error.Please  please it must need it.any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Does the error also happens locally? For example if do make the change in your dev machine (rather than directly on GoDaddy's servers).

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure your Internet app pool account can access your temp directory.
2) Make sure your drive has enough free space
3) Make sure antivirus isn't locking files with on-access scanning.